# Execute a command when files change in a directory

Tags: macos

In OS X, is there a way (shell script-ish?) to watch a directory for a file pattern and if there are any file changes to execute a command?

Comment: Although not needed, it might help to have an example: Which files do you want to watch and what should be done with them? Are you limited to using the command line or can you use AppleScript as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an app for that:

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Folder Actions Setup.app`

Select a folder to watch and a script to be executed. You can also edit the script.

Answer (score 5):

`~/Library/LaunchAgents/watch.and.lol.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>watch.and.lol</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>say</string>
        <string>lol</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>~/Desktop</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/watch.and.lol.plist` or relogin to load the agent.

There's a [launchd gotcha « Managing OS X](http://managingosx.wordpress.com/2006/05/10/launchd-gotcha/) though:

> It turns out that if a file is listed as a launchd job WatchPath, it must exist at all times, or launchd removes the path from its list of paths to watch. So you can't watch for the creation of a certain file; you can only watch for changes to the file.